# How to say "is included" in active voice

Tags: word-request

How can I say

> John is included in the Hall of Fame

but not in passive voice:

> John *X*-s the Hall of Fame

I'm looking for something different than "is in", of course :)

Comment: I can't immediately think of an answer to your question, but just a word of warning: Typically these sentences would not be described as active or passive because the notion doesn't (easily) apply to copular verbs.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly tough one actually. **@Wilson** here speaks about copular verbs, I, however, I'm not exactly sure this is one of those examples. This looks particularly like a passive voice. The problem with making it a proper active construction stands with the lack of the doer. Who included him in the Hall of Fame? Without the '*doer of the action*' we can't clearly state, thus the passive is more than welcome. You should either make the "**Hall of Fame**" the subject or include the doer as the subject.

If it were in the active it would need to be either:

- Somebody included John in the Hall of Fame.
- The Hall of Fame includes John.

In most cases we can use the very same verb in both the passive and the active and this works with "**include**" as well:

1. Breakfast is included in the price.
2. The price includes breakfast.

However, if we consider "**is**" to be the verb and "**included**" to be the adjective then we have get a different construction:

- John is *(there)* in the Hall of Fame.
- John is part of the Hall of Fame.

It's a simple emphasis on that John is a part of the Hall of Fame or belongs to it.

Comment: For me, John is the doer. He _verb_-s the Hall of Fame. As an example: in Russian it would be "_John enters (or comes in) the Hall of Fame_" (the same verb as in "_John enters the house_" which could make the phrase a bit ambiguous if the hall of fame is a real hall. But in Russian it's totally ok to say "Mary Smith enters/comes in the top-10 of best selling authors".

Comment: @Drossel In Russian it most often is "Кто-то входит в десятку" whereas in English it can be very different depending on the style and the formal/informal register. You aren't right that in this case John is the doer, a third-person is the doer, one that isn't mentioned. He cannot include himself in the Hall of Fame.

Comment: I don't see how "cannot include himself" is a good argument here. It's not about including, it's about being in. The price also cannot include the breakfast _itself_. But still it includes it. A year **consists** (<- is a doer) of four seasons and twelve months but it's not the year itself who divides a year into those parts.

Comment: 'The price includes' means that the price exists in such a way that something is part of it. So does the Hall of Fame when it "includes". 'A year consists' has the same approach. A year exists in such a way to be a combination of twelve month or 4 seasons, where each season consists of 3 month.

Comment: And John exists in such a way to be a member of the Hall of Fame. So I don't understand why you say that John cannot a doer here (but price can!) although you clearly understand this concept as a Russian speaker.

Comment: @Drossel You seem to be getting too far away from simple explanations. If you have spare time, please write to me in https://vk.com/sovereign89 or in skype: rogue_csm.

Comment: @Drossel - At least in English grammar, John is not the doer.  That's what the passive voice in "John is included" means: John is being acted upon by someone else, just like how in "The fish is eaten by a cat", the fish is not the doer. If you want to make John the actor in the sentence, you can rephrase it as something like "John is in the Hall of Fame" (like SovereignSun said!) but he isn't acting upon the Hall of Fame.

Comment: @stangdon That is exactly what I am asking - is there a verb except "to be" to say that?

Comment: @Drossel - I don't think so.  I don't think we have a verb that means "to be a member of".

Answer (score 0):

To take it out of passive voice, you'd have to make the Hall of Fame the subject: "The Hall of Fame includes John." However, that would be a strange transition if you've been talking about John. If you don't want to say "John is in the Hall of Fame" or "John is an inductee in the Hall of Fame," then this is a good example of a place where the passive voice is highly appropriate.